# How to incorporate a CCK form and view into a single page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Using Drupal 6.

I've created a new node type with CCK, which has one form field, in text, limited to 120 characters. The title is hidden by the node_autotitles module, and the body is removed by removing the body field name in the node settings.

I also have a view that displays all nodes of this type on a page view.

What I would like to do is consolidate things so that the user can fill in this node form on the view page, and have it refresh or something similar so they can see the updated page. I guess it's like a shoutbox, but I don't want to install a new module for all of this, I would like to see how it's possible using what I've created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it via blocks.
create some page, let's say shoutbox, then create 2 blocks and put them to content or content_bottom region (it depends on your theme).
in first block output form using custom php code
in second one, display your view with nodes.

Comment: Ah, so I'd need to write a module to display the node type form in a block?

Comment: nop, you can do it via admin interface.

of course you can do it via custom module, that's would be better. and module itself won't be too big.

Actually, you already have page where your view displays nodes, right? so then you just need to check if your theme has content_top region, and just put block with form into in, that's it.

in this block, it should be php code <?php return drupal_get_form("yournodetype_node_form");
?>

Comment: Ok, so I can insert that PHP into the block. But can you explain the "yournodetype" part of the argument string? Is it the machine readable name of the node type (in this case "twitter_style_post")?

Comment: right, that's it. Each node add/edit form has it's unique ID, {node_type}_node_form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [formblock](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module for achieving this, putting the node creation form in your view page.
For putting the form in your view, you can use context, panels, o whatever you're using. Or just create a module and put the form in the `#prefix` of the view with `hook_views_prerender` and `drupal_get_form`.